# How to load SCORM file from CDN in Moodle

Tags: moodle, scorm

I am working in LMS application using Moodle 3.8. We are having training with SCORM files. SCORM files are having 500 MB. We are facing issue in loading time when 30k+ user accessing the application. TO improve the performance. Planning to move the SCORM files in CDN. Is there anyway to access the SCORM from CDN? How to configure the course file from CDN?

Regards
Girija

Answer (score 1):

SCORM does not work across different domains as it tries to invoke methods on the parent window/frame. You would need a wrapper frame residing on the CDN's domain that forwards API calls e.g. using `window.postMessage` but this is not supported by Moodle as far as I know.